# How can I find out all client IP's connected and working with couchbase and send it to the log file

Tags: couchbase

How can I find out all client IP's connected and working with couchbase at the moment and save this information in the log file!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with a specific problem you have - ideally presenting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. There is no continuous connection maintained between each client and the Couchbase system. Each query is sent as a separate HTTP request.

Comment: I think this behavior may vary by service. The Key/Value service, for example, does allow clients to establish persistent connections. You can see this in the "connections" metric of the "Server Resources" section of the bucket statistics. I'm not sure how to extract the client IPs, though.